# Using method from Class to change class

Tags: c#, class

I wanted to create a class and use a method from the initialized class to change the property values of the calling instance. Somehow I have a knot in my brain and there seems to be a basic thinking error of mine. Maybe someone can help me figure it out.

```
Class Program
{
    ...
    private void Initialize()
    {
        Zoo myZoo = new Zoo();
        myZoo.Load();
        Console.WriteLine(myZoo.ZooName);
    }
}
```

and the Zoo-Class:

```
public class Zoo
{
    public string ZooName { get; set; }
    ...

    internal void Load()
    {
        Zoo myZoo = this;

        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Areas.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            myZoo = (Zoo) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Zoo));
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON part works fine, but as soon as the Load()-method comes to an end the myZoo/this is set to NULL. Is there any possibility to use 'this' to modify the property values of the calling class instance?

Comment: It is not sensible code, that probably doesn't help diagnosing what goes wrong.  Significant odds that nothing went wrong.  Do this the correct way, write a factory method.  Create a public static method (say LoadZoo) that returns Zoo.  And consider to make the constructor private.

Comment: Are you looking for the [`Populate`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Populate.htm) method instead of `Deserialize`?

Comment: I also wanted to implement a Save() method. So just to set a static Load that gives me back a completly new Object is the wrong approach, but I didn't mention that till now. :) But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

other way out.you can use ref keyword for the same.

```
Class Program
{
    ...
    private void Initialize()
    {
        Zoo myZoo = new Zoo();
        myZoo.Load(ref myZoo);
        Console.WriteLine(myZoo.ZooName);
    }
}

public class Zoo
{
    public string ZooName { get; set; }
    ...

    internal void Load(ref Zoo myZoo)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Areas.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            myZoo = (Zoo) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Zoo));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to make a factory method on your class instead. This function will return a new instance of `Zoo` with the data from your json file.

Like this:

```
public class Zoo
{
    public string ZooName { get; set; }
    ...

    public static Zoo Init()
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Areas.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var myZoo = (Zoo) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Zoo));
            return myZoo;
        }
    }
}
```

In your `Initialize` function you can now create an instance like this:

```
private void Initialize()
{
    var myZoo = Zoo.Init();
    Console.WriteLine(myZoo.ZooName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `set` the `this` pointer. There also is no assignment operator in C# to overload.

You could copy all properties from your loaded zoo object into the this object.

A more common approach is to have a static factory method to do this for you:

```
public class Zoo
{
    public string ZooName { get; set; }
    ...

    public static Zoo Load(string file)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return (Zoo) serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Zoo));
        }
    }
}
```

Later call it like this:

```
Zoo z = Zoo.Load(@"C:\Areas.json");
```